# Mock parent class behaviour (protected method) when testing child

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

I am using **Spock** to unit test project I've just joined. There is a problem however with writing tests for Java code.

```
class Parent {
   private SomeObject obj;
   public SomeObject getSomeObject() {return obj;}
   public void setSomeObject(final SomeObject obj) {this.obj = obj}
}

// THIS IS THE CLASS I AM TESTING
class Child extends Parent {
   public String doSth() {
       getSomeObject().dosomethingontheobject()  // This line causes problem
   }    
}
```

This is the test method that I am using

```
def 'test'() {
   given:
   SomeObject obj = Mock()
   obj.dosomethingontheobject() >> [somethin1, somethin2]

   Child child = new Child()
   child.setSomeObject(obj)

   when:
   child.doSth()

   then:
   1 * obj.dosomethingontheobject()
}
```

When running I am getting 'too few invocations' error for calling 'dosomethingonobject()' method.

Comment: Can you post [mcve]? I have tried to reproduce your problem - `Parent`, `Child` and `SomeObject` as Java classes, Spock test copy-pasted (`somethin1` and `somethin2` replaced with some random strings) and test passed as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will it work this way:

```
def 'test'() {
   given:
   SomeObject obj = Mock()

   Child child = new Child()
   child.setSomeObject(obj)

   when:
   child.doSth()

   then:
   1 * obj.dosomethingontheobject() >> [somethin1, somethin2]
}
```

?

Also:

```
public void getSomeObject() {return obj;}
```

`void` and `return`? ;)

Comment: @Chlebik, sure. It happens. Will you correct it in the question?